# Pandas won't create CSV file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, websocket

just trying to save websockets to CSV's. But it just doesnt make the file. Nothing in the directory. Tried running VScvode as admin, moving folder out of C: drive to documents .. nothing. no csv file, and no error. and no information on the internet about this either.

So i kept stripping down the code to the most basic, and it still wont create the file

The dataframe is in-tact and working, and printing the dataframe gets this :

```
      e              E        s                k
B  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT                0
L  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT        920866977
Q  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT  166707.65228800
T  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT    1659568739999
V  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT     103.43430000
c  kline  1659568703134  ETHUSDT    1611.00000000
```

... (continued)

```
import websocket, json, numpy, pandas
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m/btcusdt@kline_1m"
    #lol
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    df = pandas.read_json(message)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('my_new_file.csv')

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: `import os` and then add `print(os.path.abspath('my_new_file.csv'))` just before the `to_csv` to get the full directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

This will give you the file directory that the file is currently running on, so you can drop the file there.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed it would create the .CSV next to my .py file in my documents and not some temporary folder. So, accounting for the unicode error with t"C:\..." and simply specifying the directory, it works!    df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Documents\CSVtest\my_new_file.csv", index=False)